# Error while installing informatica 8.6 with oracle 11g in window 10

Tags: oracle11g, installation, data-warehouse, informatica

I am getting below error while installing informatica 8.6:

```
****use the error below and catalina.out and node.log in the server/tomcat/logs directory on the current machine to get more information. Select Retry to continue the installation.
STDOUT: Installing the service '"Informatica Services 8.6.0"' on node 'node01_geettika4912'...
Using CURRENT_DIR:      C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\tomcat\bin
Using INFA_HOME:        C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0
The service '"Informatica Services 8.6.0"' has been installed.
STDERR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The service name is invalid.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.**
EXITCODE: 2**
```

I am getting this error after the  successful creation of domain.
Please help me in resolving this error.
Thanks!

Comment: So... what do the log files in *server/tomcat/logs* say?

Comment: Check permission of the user you are using to install/ run that infa services. It need to  have RWX permission on C:\Informatica

Comment: der is no log created in the tomcat directory.

Answer (score 0):

Run services.msc to get a list of all the services.

Click properties on the service you want, there you can see the "service name" and the "display name".

The service name is what you need to use with the net command. Check if Informatica Services 8.6.0 is in the list.